# How could I bring up security concerns at the church that I attend?

Tags: church-local, united-states

I currently attend a church on Sundays, and this church serves as a synagogue on other days of the week.  Currently, there is a bit of security at the entrance, e.g. some security guards in uniform, but they are not police and do not appear to be armed.  We get scanned by metal detectors before entering.

How could I bring up security concerns to this church, say, during coffee hour after the Sunday Service?

Basically, I wonder how prepared they are to counter something like a terrorist attack.

I don't want to offend anyone - how could I inquire about this politely?

Comment: Why do you think you'll get a useful answer on the internet when the people you need to talk to, the real world, right there at the building where you go, are people that you will see again soon?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It has to be said, we on the intertoobz can help people overcome their reluctance to engage with their congregations' leaders.

Comment: @djc our site was originally chartered to deal with the business or running a Christian church as well as theology, I think it's OK -> https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/broaden-scope-to-include-church-management

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @KenGraham United States, Northeast region - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Uniformed security at a church is uncommon enough that you can use it as a conversation opener.

If I were you I would seek out a (non-clergy) trustee / deacon / elder / congregation-council member / whatever and simply ask "what's up with the guards?"  That should open the topic, and you will likely learn something about the congregation's history and struggles.

How do you find the person to talk to if you don't already know them? Easy: ask a person who serves coffee for an introduction.

Believe me: asking polite questions of lay leaders honors their offices; they'll love it. Don't hesitate.